# Firebase: How to force database to store values in the order they are entered?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

At the moment, Firebase doesn't stores the data in the order it is entered. For ex - There could be 2 existing childs and a new child is inserted, that new child goes and sits in the middle of the already existing ones! I guess this works by alphabet order but I want to store data in the correct order only.

```
firebase.database().ref('someChildRef').set({
    //Could insert anywhere
});
```

I think push could insert it in the correct order but push also generates a unique key which I don't want, I want to insert data only using set and in the correct order.

Comment: Not possible. Use query rules to bring back the data in the order you want it.

Comment: @theblindprophet Thanks, `orderByChild()` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to insert data into Firebase into a desired position. Firebase data is sorted alphabetically and all newly inserted data will be rearranged accordingly.

Use [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) rules to return the data in the order you want.

Such as:

- `orderByChild()`
- `orderByKey()`
- `orderByValue()`
- `equalTo()`

You are correct about `push()`, it will always create a unique key and add to the end, just as pushing to an array will add to the end.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for Firebase's `push()` method, which generates a unique key based on the timestamp:

```
firebase.database().ref('someChildRef').set({
    //Will result at "the end"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var messageListRef = new Firebase('https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/message_list');
var newMessageRef = messageListRef.push();
newMessageRef.set({ 'user_id': 'fred', 'text': 'Yabba Dabba Doo!' });
// We've appended a new message to the message_list location.
var path = newMessageRef.toString();
```

Try using the `push()` method instead of set. According to their docs:

> The unique name generated by push() is prefixed with a client-generated timestamp so that the resulting list will be chronologically-sorted.

Reference: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html